# How do you write if else statement for image in android?

Tags: android, eclipse

I would like to ask on  how to write IF ELSE statement.
My "if" is working fine, however, for the else, 
i couldn't get it working.
I not sure what is working with the code.

```
if(weatherCode.equals("28"))
{
    mHandler.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // This gets executed on the UI thread so it can safely modify
            // Views

             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
        }
    });
}
else
{
  image.setImageResource(R.drawable.old);
}
```

Comment: Did you try with a `weatherCode` with value different than 28?

Comment: Hi, yes. But it didn't work.

Comment: Is it really String or Integer?

Comment: @Febbie is weatherCode value string or what?

Comment: actually in the URL im getting from is int.
but i declare as string

  Node conditionNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:condition").item(0);


      String weatherCode = conditionNode.getAttributes()
            .getNamedItem("code")
            .getNodeValue()
            .toString();

Comment: why dont you add the mhandler for the else statement too? or is the else statement never executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i read the question the image is not being set correctly in the `else` part

UI actions need to be on the UI thread 
in the `else` case set the image in a new thread similar to previous action

```
else {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.old);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use thread as used in `if` part, as I added in comment too.

```
if(weatherCode.equals("28"))
{
mHandler.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // This gets executed on the UI thread so it can safely modify
        // Views

         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
    }
});
}
else {
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.old);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: @Febbie: Keep on accepting and up-voting answers and you will get more answers on your posts :)

Comment: thanks
I would like to check with you, if I would like to do as else if
is it like this?
else if ( weatherCode.equals("15")) {
              mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                
                  public void run() {

                      image.setImageResource(R.drawable.old);
                  }
              });
          }
     
          else  {
              mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
               
                  public void run() {

                      image.setImageResource(R.drawable.new);
                  }
              });
          }

Comment: @Febbie: Out of curiosity, are you doing this in an `AsyncTask`?

Comment: yes just add the Handler and runnable for each else-if and else :)

Comment: @SiddharthLele Hi,Nope. I'm not

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal Can I ask , what  does handler and runnable dO in the statements?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!weatherCode
        && weatherCode.equals("28")) {

    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This gets executed on the UI thread so it can safely
            // modify
            // Views

            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
        }
    });

} else {
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.old);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the comment in your code provides already the right hint.
In the if case you use a handler to make the image manipulation code run on the UI thread, but for your else case you don't.